# Change the icon of all the folders on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: mac, folders, icon, catalina

I've updated to Mac OS Catalina and my folders no longer have my custom icons. I tried following the steps shown [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268582/change-the-icon-of-all-the-folders-on-mac/268587#268587). I successfully turned off SIP via csrutil disable in recovery mode, however I still can not modify the folder icons in the directory /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources. Is it not possible to do in Catalina or is there an additional step now?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I turned off SIP again, went to that directory in the terminal, ran that command, used "open ." then tried to drag the new icon file and it won't let me drop it or make any changes in that directory.