# How do I write to /System/Library/CoreServices on Big Sur?

Tags: mac, permission, big-sur

I'm trying to give myself privileges to read & write on the GenericFolderIcon.icns file in resource, but it's giving me this error "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission."

The file I'm having an issue with is found here: /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources
The folder icon is named *GenericFolderIcon.icns*

I followed the steps in the answers from this past thread: [Change the icon of all the folders on mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268582/change-the-icon-of-all-the-folders-on-mac) ...and it isn't working
I planed on swapping the folder icon with my own .incs file by editing the names.

I'm also the administrator of my laptop it's running 11.0.1 Big Sur.
andd System Integrity Protection is disabled.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? Did you disable SIP? Also the linked question has two answers, "I followed the steps from this past thread even the ones in the replies" doesn't give us much in what exactly you did so can you please add the steps you've done (and the result if it wasn't as expected) to your question.

Comment: I'm on 11.0.1 Big Sur
I did disable SIP. I'm trying to give myself privileges to read & write on the GenericFolderIcon.icns file in resource, but it's giving me an error "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission."
I'm the administrator on my laptop and the only user. 

Thank you for helping me btw I really appreciate it!!

Comment: The permission system changed with Catalina and again with Big Sur, the method may just not work anymore now. But as I said: edit the question with details if you want to have the hold removed.

Comment: Did I edit it right?

Comment: The essentials are here now, yes. Let's see whether somebody has an answer.

Comment: This is one of those times I'm going to say it... If you have to ask how to do it, you really should not even attempt to do it! The system volume is read-only and is cryptographically signed for very good reasons! I've read on-line, but haven't tested, that if using FileVault, it has to be disable to break the seal and then FileVault cannot be enabled there after, as well as the issues too. Keep out of the engine room unless you are a certified mechanic!